# AngularJS - Where can I find, in the framework, the logic behind the "required" and not "ng-required" attribute?

Tags: angularjs, frameworks, custom-data-attribute

The question is as simple as it is described in the "Title" :)

I just want to be able to put a break-point in the non-minified version of the AngularJS framework and see the logic that is executed when you try to submit a form that has an empty input with the "required" attribute. This logic should normally check if the input is not empty. The "this.$isEmpty = function(value) {...}" or "requiredDirective" are not hit when you click submit!

E.g. from AngularJS official site (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms):

```
<form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
    Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" name="uName" required=""/>
    <br/>

    <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.uName.$touched">
        <div ng-show="form.uName.$error.required">Tell us your name.</div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" ng-click="update(user)" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Here you go: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L2647

Comment: pixelbits, i tried to put a breakpoint inside the requiredDirective, "link" function, and the breakpoint is not hit...